# Check for modified code using inspect element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security, browser

I am facing some security issue on my legacy Java application. Is there any way to identify that my code (HTML or script) has been changed by the Developer Tools on the client, so I can stop the form submission or the performing any other task?

Comment: There no way to stop this. For this reason, you should always check the content of any requests on the server-side to make sure that nothing has been tampered with.

Comment: You can do that, but the developer can change the code that stopping the submission...

Comment: I know @RoryMcCrossan about the server-side security but It will be so expensive in a huge legacy java application.

Comment: Checking the DOM state on each request will be even more expensive.

Comment: Hello @Amina, I just want to know that if a user change anything in html or script by inspect element and then perform any task on the web page like click a button , So How can I find that the user have changed something in the real code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent such modifications, but what you can do is to make some server side security checks to prevent such forgery.

You can add a hidden input in a form with a hashed token that represents the basic form data (key for example (entity_id+user_id)) or anything that you want to make sure has not changed.

In this case when the form is submitted you can make sure after de-hashing the hidden input token, that the entity id (or any other data) the user is editing for instance has not been changed where the submitted values match the token de-hash and that the user has edited the elements he shall only be editing.